# OrientDB Merge Objects in Functions

Tags: function, object, merge, orientdb

Is there any default function to merge objects in Orient DB Java Script Function. Sample data given below.

**Sample Data:**

```
[{
   "AA": {            
        "AA Version": "",
        "AA Exp Version": "N/A",
        "AA Status": "Warning"            
    },
    "BB": {           
        "BB Version": "",
        "BB Exp Version": "N/A",
        "BB Status": "Warning"            
    }
}]
```

**Expected Output:**

```
[{
    {            
        "AA Version": "",
        "AA Exp Version": "N/A",
        "AA Status": "Warning",         
        "BB Version": "",
        "BB Exp Version": "N/A",
        "BB Status": "Warning"            
    }
}]
```

Thanks in advance.